# Changing things in Wordpress themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the next problem:
I'm an owner of a page in wordpress as admin and I want to do some changes to the page but I don't know where I can change it and how to edit them:

I want to change words "days", "horas", "minutos" and "seconds" of:

### [image]

To the letters "D", "H", "M" and "S".
I have the dunamis theme and this is the page (if it is useful by any reason): http://calvarynorte.org/

Comment: Have you tried asking the theme developer? Seems like dunamis is a paid theme, you should be able to get some support from theme http://cro.ma/?page_id=160

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately every theme is created differently. Without being able to see the code of your theme it is hard to say where the code for your countdown timer is stored. The only advice I can give is to refer to the massively useful [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and have a go at working this out yourself, you never know... you may get hooked.

Regards

Dan

Answer (score 0):

This come on the Template file which is create on theme root directory.
open that file and change on that.

Otherwise
go->Theme Editor->select Template file and edit.